# Convert string to datetime in javascript and compare with current time

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-to-datetime

I am trying to pick up value from datetimepicker tetxbox and compare those values with current time.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jah79yhj/)

```
        //startTime textbox text = 19/12/2014 03:58 PM
        var startTime = Date.parse($('[id$=txtStartDate]').val().toString());

        //endTime textbox text = 19/12/2014 04:58 PM
        var endTime = Date.parse($('[id$=txtEndDate]').val().toString());

        var currentTime = Date.now();
        alert(startTime);
        alert(endTime);
        alert(currentTime);

        if (currentTime >= startTime && currentTime <= endTime) {
              alert();

        }
```

Date.parse() is used fro converting string to milliseconds since Jan 1 1970.
Date.now() returns current date milliseconds since Jan 1 1970.

But the above conversion methods are not working properly.
What should be logic to compare datetime by first sonverting string in format like **19/12/2014 03:58 PM** to Date object and then do comparing.

Comment: I have edited JsFiddle

Comment: hello please check this link http://jsfiddle.net/3mztdaja/2/

Comment: You are using a date picker, can you throw up the link as I find it unlikely that any such plugin wouldn't have a parser included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that format [isn't documented as being supported by `Date.parse`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15), your best bet is to parse it yourself, which isn't difficult: Use [`String#split`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.14) or a regular expression with capture groups to split it into the individual parts, use [`parseInt`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.2.2) to convert the parts that are numeric strings into numbers (or, with controlled input like this, just use the unary `+` on them), and then use [`new Date(...)`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.1) to use those numbers to create a `Date` instance.

One gotcha: The `month` value that `new Date` expects is **zero-based**, e.g. 0 = January. Also remember to add 12 to the hours value if the input uses AM/PM instead of the 24-hour clock.

---

Or, of course, use any of several date/time handling libraries, such as [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is `Date()` expects date format mm/dd/yyyy, so your date is invalid.

You can fix your date like this:

```
function toValidDate(datestring){
    return datestring.replace(/(\d{2})(\/)(\d{2})/, "$3$2$1");   
}

var startTime = Date.parse(toValidDate($('[id$=txtStartDate]').val().toString())); 
var endTime = Date.parse(toValidDate($('[id$=txtEndDate]').val().toString()));    
var currentTime = Date.now();

alert(startTime);
alert(endTime);
alert(currentTime);
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/3mztdaja/3/

Answer (score 1):

You should use this method

```
var startTime  = new Date(year, month, day, hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds);
```

this a demo http://jsfiddle.net/hswp7x8k/

to extrat value from string you can use this method

```
dd = '19/12/2014 03:58';
dd.match(/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\s*(\d+):(\d+)/);
```

this a demo http://jsfiddle.net/w3wow1ay/2/